# Find the average spacing between an array of numbers

Tags: statistics

If I had an array of 7 numbers and I wanted all numbers to be equally spaced within it but needed to start at 5 and end at 35 how would I do this?

For instance if I were given:

- Numbers in array: **7**
- Largest number in array: **35**
- Smallest number in array: **5**

How do I find what number to increment the array by if I wanted to create an array of equally spaced numbers?

An example answer would be: Given the above three numbers I would say increment each array position by 5 and all 7 numbers will be equally spaced all the way to 35. The end result would look like this: [5,10,15,20,25,30,35]

**Question 1**: What would the formula be to repeat this any time I have array length, smallest, and largest number?

**Question 2**: In the above example if I were given the number 30 what is the formula to find its position in the given array? The formula should produce a result like this: If the array started at index one it would be position 6.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

- How many gaps between consecutive pairs of numbers? *In your example, $7-1=6$*
- What do the gaps add up to? *In your example, $35-5=30$*
- What is the size of a gap? *In your example, $\frac{30}{6}=5$*
- suppose there was a value before the first; what would it be? (call this the zeroth value) *In your example, $5-5=0$*
- how many gaps would you need to add to the zeroth value to get your target value? *In your example, $\frac{30}{5}=6$*

So the $n$th value would be the zeroth value plus $n$ gaps, while value $x$ would be in the position corresponding to $x$ minus the zeroth value, all divided by the gap size

Answer (score 1):

We have 2 numbers, $a,b$ with $a<b$. Suppose we want $c$ numbers in the array. Then the array would look like this: $(a,a+d,a+2d,....,a+(c-2)d,b)$ For some number $d$. Notice that the difference between any consecutive numbers in the array is $d$ (by construction). Using this fact, $b-(a+(c-2)d)=d.$ (last number in array minus penultimate) which we can solve for $d$ to obtain $d=(b-a)/(c-1)$ and $c \neq 1$ since we always have at least 2 numbers in the array.